# neo4j cypher: return invert relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are using neo4j v4.

I have USER, COMPUTER, COMPANY nodes(IBM, HP, DELL etc),

When company is IBM, I want to reverse the edge before returning.

I tried apoc.refactor.invert() like below:

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: 101})
RETURN  
CASE u.preference 
WHEN 'HP'    THEN  [(n:computer)-[r: MANUFACTURED_BY]->(c:HP) | r]
WHEN 'IBM'   THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBELED_BY]->(c:IBM) | apoc.refactor.invert(r)] 
WHEN 'DELL'   THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBELED_BY]->(c:DELL) | r] 
WHEN 'HP_IBM' THEN xxxxxxx END
AS result;
```

But, getting this error: Invalid input 's'

Any idea?

Comment: Do you actually want to save the invert of those relationships to the graph, or did you only want to return virtual relationships with that change to the user and leave the graph alone?

Comment: I want to leave the graph alone and return the inverted relationship when preference is 'IBM'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [apoc.create.vRelationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.vRelationship/) to return virtual `ASSEMBLED_BY` relationships (with reversed directionality) for `IBM` users. This does not change any relationships in the DB.

```
MATCH (u:USER {id: 101})
RETURN CASE u.preference 
  WHEN 'HP'     THEN [(n:computer)-[r: MANUFACTURED_BY]->(c:HP) | r]
  WHEN 'IBM'    THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBLED_BY]->(c:IBM) | apoc.create.vRelationship(c, 'ASSEMBLED_BY', PROPERTIES(r), n)] 
  WHEN 'DELL'   THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBLED_BY]->(c:DELL) | r] 
  WHEN 'HP_IBM' THEN [(n:computer)-[r:ASSEMBLED_BY]->(c:HP_IBM) | r] END
AS result;
```

Note that the above query uses the correctly-spelled `ASSEMBLED_BY` relationship type.

Comment: Thank you @cybersam, it fits my need perfectly!